# Pass string with spaces as system argument c++

Tags: c++

If I have a path(string) with spaces, for example `"C:\\Users\\Irina\\Desktop\\POO\\PROIECT POO\\my file.docx"` and I want to open that file, I use the system command like this

```
system(path.c_str())
```

And I get the following error :

'C:\Users\Irina\Desktop\POO\PROIECT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I would really appreciate some help.
Thanks :)

Comment: Enclose it in double quotes, as in `system(("\"" + path + "\"").c_str());`

Comment: thank you, it solved the problem !

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the string in double quotes:

```
    system(('"' + path + '"').c_str());
```

Comment: Original comment by [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) - so marked as community wiki